# SQL Server synchronization failed

Tags: sql-server-2005, synchronization, sql-server

I'm getting the error message below when trying to synchronize a SQL compact database (SQL CE 2.0) to a SQL Server 2005 database.

I have double and triple checked permissions, reconfigured IIS multiple times, and I've run Process Monitor to see that the .IN/.OUT files are being created in my temporary directory.

Error Messages:
Initializing SQL Server Reconciler has failed. Try again.
HRESULT 0x80045901 (29045)

The merge process could not initialize the message file from Subscriber 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server CE 2.0\Server\CE578B80-DE68-11CB-8000-F391ABB1F993.IN:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server CE 2.0\Server\CE578B80-DE68-11CB-8000-F391ABB1F993.OUT'. (Source: Merge Replication Provider, Error number: -2147198719)

The operation could not be completed.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I sould try next to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link and see if it helps you out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172357.aspx  It is for SQL Compact 3.5 though.

Quoted below from this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/41728924-0fac-4ddb-9680-c30ae8426fb8

> Your SQL Server name/credentials are
>   not working:
>
> Failure to connect to SQL Server with
>   provided connection information. SQL
>   Server does not exist, access is
>   denied because the IIS user is not a
>   valid user on the computer running SQL
>   Server, or the password is incorrect.

Comment: Unfortunately that solution applies not to the initial problem mentioned in that thread, but to fix an error that occurs after reinstall.